# suggestions on data visualization app

Tags: database, data-visualization, data-analysis, rest

Please note that I am new to data visualization and I'm looking for suggestions on what data visualization app to use.

Use cases:

1. Lots of records in a mysql database from different users.
2. each record has several fields, such as user_name, date, geolocation, ip, host and so on;
3. each user can query on his own data and visualize them to map, bars, pie graphs according to time (weeks, months, years), countries, ips, and so on.
4. queries or query result should be stored. 5, each user can not access other users' data

In my opinion, the architecture should looks like:

database --> django/data aggregator --> RESTful APIs --> angular (?)

I have some questions:

1. Are there any good docs about this kind of applications for me to learn? good examples, architecture design? how to guarantee scalability and speed?
2. Are there good libraries to do data aggregation/visualization which can be integrated with Django?
3. angular is enough for the frontend?
4. how to separate the backend and frontend? should APIs return data or imgs?

Comment: Please note that [items 1+4 are off-topic here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) (and item 3 is at least border-line). The remaining item 2 needs specific requirements listed – e.g. for which programming language, what price limit you have, license concerns (e.g. for commercial use). Please [edit] and adjust your post accordingly. Thanks!